# Creating a swift list of functions

Tags: ios, list, swift, functional-programming, closures

So I want to create a list of functions that have no parameters and return void, how do I do this?

This is what I have so far:

```
var levels: [() -> ()] = [() -> ()]()
```

But this just gives me a "Expected ',' seperator" Error

Anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell that **should** work. It looks like the problem is where you initialize the array:

```
[() -> ()]()
```

I've tried that in Xcode 6.0.1 and Xcode 6.0 GM and it fails in both places. A workaround is to use the `Array<T>` syntax instead:

```
var levels: [() -> ()] = Array<() -> ()>()
```

**Edit:** This also works:

```
var levels: [() -> ()] = []
```